# Identifying entries that have any overlap with reference times using dplyr R

Tags: r, dplyr, overlap, between

I have a set of audio clips from different sites and files that I have manually extracted and a set that have been extracted automatically. I want to identify any clips in the automatically extracted set at the same site and file that overlap at all with those in the manually extracted set.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
group <- as.factor(round(runif(100, 1, 10),0))
file <- sample(LETTERS, 100, TRUE)
start <- round(runif(100, 0, 100), 2)
end <- round(start + (runif(100, 0, 1)), 2)

auto <- bind_cols(group, file, start, end) %>% 
        set_names(., nm = c("group", "file", "start", "end"))

man <- bind_rows(sample_n(auto, 10) %>% 
       mutate(start = round(start - runif(10, 0, 1), 2), 
              end = round(end - runif(10,0, 0.5), 2)), 
                 sample_n(auto, 10) %>% 
       mutate(start = round(start + runif(10, 0, 1), 2), 
              end = round(start + runif(10,0, 0.5), 2)))
```

I have been trying to use `dplyr::between` like this:

```
res <- auto %>% 
  left_join(., man, by = c("group", "file")) %>%  
  drop_na() %>% 
  mutate(pos = (between(start.x, start.y, end.y) | between(end.x, start.y, end.y)))
```

But it is just returning `FALSE`. The code doesn't throw an error so I am guessing there is in issue in the way I have written it.

If you split out the or in the last `mutate` to check if either `between` function is the issue, like this:

```
res <- auto %>% 
  left_join(., man, by = c("group", "file")) %>%  
  drop_na() %>% 
  mutate(x = between(start.x, start.y, end.y),
         y = between(end.x, start.y, end.y),
         pos = x | y  == "TRUE")
```

you can see that both return `FALSE`.

It seems like it should be a relatively simple thing, but I am struggling to figure it out.

Comment: Are you just looking for `mutate(pos = (between(start.x, start.y, end.y) | between(end.x, start.y, end.y)))`? Seems like a typo.

Comment: @arg0naut91 you are right in saying I don't need the ```== "TRUE"``` but when I run it without as you suggested I still get the same result, all ```FALSE```. I have updated the question with your suggestion.

Comment: You're right, actually I forgot about this while I've encountered same issues: `dplyr::between` doesn't work with vectors on left and right side, I believe in these cases it just recycles the first result (i.e. you get all `FALSE`). Try `data.table::between` and it should work. But it's all written in documentation as well - it''s just not intuitive, I agree.

Comment: Brilliant! It works, thank you so much @arg0naut91